# How to update cell value in Excel table using VBA and Match function?

Tags: excel, vba, match, cell

not a VBA pro here, but doing my best...

The goal is to create a Macro that updates a cell value in a table based on the table row variable from Application.Match function, which I am also struggling with. Here's what I have so far and where I'm lost (also commented into the code).

1. I can't seem to get the match function to set my TargetRw variable to the matched row in the table. As it is currently i'm getting 'Type Mismatch', but I've attempted several different configurations and received a variety of different errors.
2. If i can get the match to work, I'd like to be able to set the cell value of the TargetRw and table Column "Reviewed Rate" = to the value held in the 'Rate' variable. I haven't been able to find much online regarding how to reference a table range like this in order update a cell value.

   ```
   Sub ReviewTracker()

   Dim Acell As Variant
   Dim TargetRw As Long
   Dim Rate As Variant
   Dim MACMtable, RCtable, TargetTable As ListObject
   Dim LUTables As Worksheet


       Set LUTables = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("LookupTables")

       Set MACMtable = LUTables.ListObjects("MACM_Lookup")
       Set RCtable = LUTables.ListObjects("RC_Lookup")

       Asht = ActiveSheet.Name
       Acell = ActiveCell.Value
       Rate = ActiveCell.Offset(0, -3).Value

       If Asht = "Rate Codes" Then
       Set TargetTable = RCtable
       Else
       If Asht = "MACMs" Then
       Set TargetTable = MACMtable
       End If
           End If

       ***''' Can't get the TargetRw variable below to work... Type Missmatch'''***
       TargetRw = Application.Match(Acell, TargetTable.ListColumns(1), 0)

       With TargetTable
           ******'''I am trying to figure out how to set the cell corresponding to the row: TargetRw & Column 6 (name: "Reviewed Rate") to the value of the variable 'Rate'******

       .DataBodyRange.Cells(TargetRw, 6) = Rate.Value '''This doesn't seem to work, but hopefully illustrates the goal'''

       End With
   ```

   End Sub

There are 2 tables on a single worksheet (variable: 'LUTables'). One or the other would be updated depending on the activesheet at the time the Macro was initiated. Both have a column named "Reviewed Rate", which is also the 6th column in each table.

Any assistance would be very much appreciated!

Comment: hi.  Application.Match returns a double and your TargetRw is a long.  replace Dim TargetRw As Long for Dim TargetRw As double and try. good luck

Comment: Something to point out, your line 'Dim MACMtable, RCtable, TargetTable As ListObject', dimensions TargetTable as a list object and the others as variants, you need to specify each one like Dim MACMtable As ListObject, RCtable As ListObject, TargetTable As ListObject

Comment: Have you checked that `Acell` is actually found?

Comment: If there’s no match then Match returns an error value, so the receiving variable should be a variant, and you need to test for an error before proceeding

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
TargetTable.ListColumns(1)
```

should be

```
TargetTable.ListColumns(1).DataBodyRange
```

A ListColumn is not the same thing as a Range

Untested:

```
Sub ReviewTracker()

    Dim Acell As Variant, Asht As String
    Dim TargetRw As Variant '***
    Dim Rate As Variant
    Dim TargetTable As ListObject
    Dim LUTables As Worksheet

    Set LUTables = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("LookupTables")

    Asht = ActiveSheet.Name
    Acell = ActiveCell.Value
    Rate = ActiveCell.Offset(0, -3).Value

    If Asht = "Rate Codes" Then
        Set TargetTable = LUTables.ListObjects("RC_Lookup")
    ElseIf Asht = "MACMs" Then
        Set TargetTable = LUTables.ListObjects("MACM_Lookup")
    End If

    TargetRw = Application.Match(Acell, TargetTable.ListColumns(1).DataBodyRange, 0)

    If Not IsError(TargetRw) Then
        TargetTable.DataBodyRange.Cells(TargetRw, 6) = Rate '### no .Value
    End If

End Sub
```

Comment: Thanks everyone for all your help. The TargetRw variable is now working as expected however Tim's suggested line of 'TargetTable.DataBodyRange.Cells(TargetRw, 6) = Rate.Value' is generating Run-Time Error '424': Object required...?

Comment: hey @Tim, would you happen to know if this error is in reference to the TargetRw variable or the Table? or neither?  thanks

Comment: Sorry my bad - missed removing the `.Value` from `Rate` (this just a plain variable and has no `Value` property)

Comment: the weird thing is that i'd tried that already and when it executed that line, it initiated a UDF that i have in another module, which is named UserName, but takes Reference as Range... not sure how or why it called that from Rate... I thought might have something to do with the Rate variable's name and/or type so i tried renaming to myRate and changing the Dim type (Rate will either be type integer or decimal depending), but no luck with all the various combinations i tried. It either throws the error or calls the UDF

Comment: I also tried replacing = Rate with something else like = Now() and it still calls the UDF

Comment: Does it trigger the UDF because there are cells referencing that UDF on the sheet you're updating?

Comment: nothing on the active sheet... other sheets, but nothing linking them to the active sheet. The active sheet just contains a pivot table. when i hover over all the variables, their values are correct, however when i hover over the TargetTable portion of 'TargetTable.DataBodyRange.Cells(TargetRw, 6) = Rate' i don't get the table name, but i do when i hover over the variable higher up at the "Set" lines... do i need to further define TargetTable or something? like preface with LUTables?

Comment: nothing referencing the UDF on the destination sheet either

Comment: Is the UDF volatile?  Not much I can offer without access to your workbook...

Comment: I didn't think it was, but this isn't my wheelhouse... the function it's calling is this... Function UserName(Reference As Range)
If Reference.Value <> "" Then
UserName = Environ$("Username")
Else
UserName = ""
End If
End Function

Comment: If i delete the function from the workbook, it works perfectly... but i'm kind of relying on that function in some other sheets...

Comment: Do you have an event handler which is triggering the function?

Comment: Not that I know of, that function is in a table column on another sheet so that every time the user adds a new record it auto stamps their user ID. There is a similar UDF that performs a date stamp. But those are the only two functions/modules in the Wb aside from this one...?

Comment: What's the problem with that function running?