# Updating Value to First Empty cell of Column via Textbox1

Tags: excel, vba, textbox

I have been using a below piece of code that adds the `TextBox1` value into the `Col"B"` and `Col"L"` first empty cell of two column `1 is table column` and `second is range column`. Both are from different sheets.

But receiving an error `Object does not support this property and range`

Any help will be appreciated.

```
        Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()
        
Sheet37.ListObjects("Table14").ListColumns("Condition").End(xlDown).Offset(1, 0).Value = TextBox1.Value
        
Sheet5.Range("L2").End(xlDown).Offset(1, 0).Value = TextBox1.Value

ActiveCell.Value = TextBox1.Value
        
    Unload Me
        End Sub
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When i saw `Unload Me`, i am assuming that you are using `Userform` to write data on excel sheet, in your case, the error occur due to you did not mention where the `textbox` is located:

All the 3 VBA are missing `me.` that refer to `userform` that you have created:

```
Sheet37.ListObjects("Table14").ListColumns("Condition").End(xlDown).Offset(1, 0).Value = me.TextBox1.Value
        
Sheet5.Range("L2").End(xlDown).Offset(1, 0).Value = me.TextBox1.Value

ActiveCell.Value = me.TextBox1.Value
```

If you still not clear how to link `Userform-textbox-excel`, you can refer to my simple instruction on this link [Can't update a table with vba](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67664969/cant-update-a-table-with-vba/67665623#67665623)

To update the value on `ListObject Table`, you may use the following method as we need to use `databodyrange` in order to access the `cell` in Listobject:

```
Sub submit()

Dim tb1 As ListObject
Dim s As Long

Set tb1 = Sheet2.ListObjects("Table1")
s = tb1.ListRows.Count

tb1.DataBodyRange.Cells(s + 1, 1) = Me.TextBox1.Value

Unload Me

End Sub
```

Comment: Still receiving same error on this line `Sheet37.ListObjects("Table14").ListColumns("Condition").End(xlDown).Offset(1, 0).Value = me.TextBox1.Value` @Kin Siang

Comment: You may refer to how to update data in excel table on this link https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58417779/how-to-update-cell-value-in-excel-table-using-vba-and-match-function. When you are writing VBA to update data, by removing the `table` and directly update value with `range` is much simple and easier. Accept the answer if helping :)

Comment: Yes you are right you have referred me to the links. I  have gone through the links but could not find how to fix the above error which still i am Receiving. Sure i will accept this as answer when i will be able to find the error through your links. Do not worry i will accept but still struggling to sort it out, @Kin Siang

Comment: ok, let me try how to update value with table, something new for me also

Comment: You may see my edited answer, I think quite similar to `range` data, although you need to set the table at beginning